# Drawing circles and writing text on them using d3 in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, visualization

I am a new javascript programmer. I am trying to make a visualization component in which I have to draw a circle and write something on it ("basically a single letter on every circle") the code is as follows

```
    var svgcontainer = d3.select("body").append("svg") 
                                    .attr("width",width)
                                    .attr("height",height);
d3.json("real.json",function(json){

    var elem = svgcontainer.selectAll("div")
                  .data(json.residues);

    var elemEnter = elem.enter()
        .append("g");

    var circle = elemEnter.append("circle")
                          .attr("cx",50)
                          .attr("cy",50)
                          .attr("r",10)
                          .style("fill","red");

    elemEnter.append("text")
             .attr("dx",-20)
             .text(function(d){return d.name});

 }) ;
```

The code is drawing circles but not writing any letters on them. the json example file is as follows

```
{
"residues":[
    {"name":"A","mut":[
         {"what":"A1H","type":"non-neutral"}
    ]},    
    {"name":"H"}
]}
```

Please help me fix the code to draw a circle and write a letter on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 var svgcontainer = d3.select("body").append("svg") 
                                    .attr("width", 200)
                                    .attr("height",200);
//d3.json("real.json",function(json){
var json = {
"residues":[
    {"name":"A","mut":[
         {"what":"A1H","type":"non-neutral"}
    ],"cx": 50,"cy":50, "r":20},    
    {"name":"H","cx": 90,"cy":80, "r":20}
]};

    var elem = svgcontainer.selectAll("div")
                  .data(json.residues);

    var elemEnter = elem.enter()
        .append("g");

    var circle = elemEnter.append("circle")
                          .attr("cx",function(d){ return d.cx;})
                          .attr("cy",function(d){ return d.cy;})
                          .attr("r",function(d){ return d.r;})
                          .style("fill","red");

    elemEnter.append("text")
             .attr("dy", function(d){
      return d.cy+5;
    }).attr("dx",function(d){ return d.cx-5;})
             .text(function(d){return d.name});

 //}) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

```
var circle = elemEnter.append("circle")
                          .attr("cx",50)
                          .attr("cy",50)
                          .attr("r",10)
                          .style("fill","red");
```

Don't use static values to set cx, cy and r values of circle, using static values will set all the circle to be in one position, we can't see all the circles only circle will be visible.

```
elemEnter.append("text")
         .attr("dx",-20)
         .text(function(d){return d.name});
```

Here also we are setting dx value of text with -20, negative value will take the element out of svg, so we can't see the text, try to set the dx and dy values of text according to circle cx and cy values this will set both together.

I made all the changes,
Hope you got it.
If not ask me for more.

Comment: thanks for answering it was great help but i want to use large json file as data so i cannot hard code them in .js file i need to use external json file how can i do that?

Comment: Okay, tell me is your JSON structure is same as mentioned in the question.

Comment: hey you already did that ...i just saw in the comment // you have called the external file i got it thanks a lot.

Comment: hey you made a call in the comment section(//) it worked i got it, thanks a lot, i have one more question i have to create around 200 of these circles and i have to arrange them in a chain(it is a protien sequence so it is a long chain which is something like this |_|''|_|), so i want to ask how should i provide centers for all these circles so it should form a chain, should i hard code it in .js file or write some sort of function?

Comment: Okay, we can make it, could you clearly give your diagram/ visualization.

Comment: sorry i took so long to reply, i added the image with the question, it shows the chain it will be longer and will have single letter(like 'A' and 'H' in our example), and when clicked on any circle it will zoom in and show some data (like "non-neutral" in A) about bubble.